# How do I hide a `ir.actions.act_window` defined in another module

Tags: odoo

Pretty simple question. In `odoo/addons/portal/wizard/portal_wizard_views.xml` there is the following action:

```xml
<act_window id="partner_wizard_action"
    name="Grant portal access"
    binding_model="res.partner"
    res_model="portal.wizard"
    view_mode="form" target="new"
    groups="base.group_partner_manager"/>
```

How do I hide it??

### More Information

Other answers I've seen recommend unlinking the record completely, but not only could I not figure out the best way to do this, most importantly I would like to remove the action in such a way so that if my module is uninstalled, the action is show again as if nothing ever happened. I don't want my module doing anything to other modules that would require them to be reinstalled. Especially in this case, since the `portal` module is depended up by `sale` and `account`, among other critical modules.

I've also seen answers recommending just redefining the record with the same id but prefixed with the other module's name in order to override the action. In this case I guess that would look something like this:

```xml
<act_window id="portal.partner_wizard_action"
    name="Grant portal access 2"
    binding_model="res.partner"
    res_model="portal.wizard"
    view_mode="form" target="new"
    groups="base.group_partner_manager"/>
```

However, I couldn't even get this to work. It doesn't replace the existing action in the contextual menu; instead it just adds a new action, resulting in there now being two (both "Grant portal access" and "Grant portal access 2"). And I'm not sure how I would hide the action using this method either.

**Edit:** I found that for some unknown reason the original action in my Odoo instance no longer had an external ID. That is why it wasn't being "overridden" when I tried redefining the record. I resolved this my uninstalling my custom module, deleting both of the actions, and then **updating** the portal module. This caused the action to be re-created with the external ID present again, and when I reinstalled my custom module I could then override it.

However, this doesn't solve my problem of updating the action in a "non-destructive" way. When I uninstall my custom module, changes that it made to the action persist until the original `portal` module is upgraded again. This is bad, because someone uninstalling the custom module would need to know that the `portal` module must be upgraded to revert some of the changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out... sort of.

First, for some reason the original `partner_wizard_action` from the `portal` module in my case had somehow lost it's external ID/ref/xml_id. I have no clue how that happened, but to resolve it I had to uninstall my custom module, delete the "Grant portal access" action and the "Grant portal access 2" action, and then upgrade the `portal` module. This re-created the `partner_wizard_action` with the correct external ID.

I could then override the action as expected with the following code:

```xml
<record id="portal.partner_wizard_action" model="ir.actions.act_window">
    <field name="binding_model_id" eval="False"/>
</record>
```

This unbinds the action from the `res.partner` model, causing the action to no longer show up in the contextual menu. However, it does still exist.

**This "solution" comes with a huge caveat, however.** When I uninstall my custom module now, the action does not get reverted to how it was before it was overridden. So it will still be hidden, unless the `portal` module is explicitly upgraded again.

To get around this, I'm considering writing a `uninstall_hook` in my module manifest to set the action's `binding_model_id` back to the correct value. It sucks that there doesn't seem to be a better way to do this, however.

**Edit:** I was successfully able to have the action revert itself at module uninstallation using the following `uninstall_hook`:

```py
from odoo import api, SUPERUSER_ID

def uninstall_hook(cr, registry):
    env = api.Environment(cr, SUPERUSER_ID, {})
    env.ref("portal.partner_wizard_action").binding_model_id = env.ref("base.model_res_partner").id
```

In case you are not aware, you would put this function in `__init__.py` at the root of your module and then add `"uninstall_hook": "uninstall_hook"` to your `__manifest__.py` file.

Answer (score 0):

To hide an action, you can:

1- Set the binding model (`binding_model_id`) to `False`.

2- Add a group with no user so the following [expression](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/15.0/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_actions.py#L119) is evaluated to `True`:

```
 action_groups and not action_groups & user_groups
```

3- Add the `active` field (default=True) to hide action from searches then alter the [_get_bindings](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/15.0/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_actions.py#L90) method (because actions are fetched using an SQL query
) and change the `where` clause to:

```
where m.model = %s and active is true
```

4- It is also possible to alter the [fieds_view_get](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/15.0/odoo/models.py#L1727) method to filter the toolbar actions

*Adding groups may require reverting changes after module uninstallation*